# how keeping primefaces theme for all pages and session with spring security

Tags: primefaces, themes, jsf-2.2

I work with maven and netbeans 8.2. In maven pom I have:

```
org.primefaces/primefaces/7.0
org.primefaces.themes/all-themes/1.0.10
```

In my Login.xhtml page, I used themeSwitcher for the selection of a theme that the user can keep it during the whole session, without keeping theme in a database table, I was inspired by following primefaces showcase : [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/themeSwitcher.xhtml)

The change take effect only after login, when I make change theme for all pages in my index page. In my HttpSecurity configuration, I have put :

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
```

I'm new with jsf and java.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Comment: I have a deja-vu...

Comment: Right ! I have make mistake, I delete my before post :-)

Answer (score 0):

That work, only  after user login and put :

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>#{themeSwitcherView.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and initialise variable **theme** in

```
   @PostConstruct
public void init() {
    theme="omega";
    themes = service.getThemes();
}
...
public String getTheme() {
    return theme;
}

public void setTheme(String theme) {
    this.theme = theme;
}

public void saveTheme(AjaxBehaviorEvent ajax) {   
    setTheme((String) ((ThemeSwitcher)ajax.getSource()).getValue());
}
```